# how does one find out which dpi folder a given device will use?

Tags: android, resolution

I'm unclear on the relationship between resolution, ppi, and which drawable folder a device will natively pull art from.

Specifically I'm trying to figure out the RAZR M's spec, but in general, is there some formula one can apply to figure this out?  I'm not seeing it on the android dev doc, though maybe I'm overlooking it?

TIA

Comment: This is covered rather extensively in the documentation, such as http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html and http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html and http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html and probably others. You might consider editing your question to be substantially more specific about what you are unclear on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at some Google results like:
[generator](http://members.ping.de/~sven/dpi.html)
or [explanation](http://www.brandbuildercompany.com/blog/2012/03/29/device-independent-pixel-formula-for-mobile-devices/)  if you want to know the 'magic' behind it.

And on the Android development site you can find an overview of the density buckets:
[Density buckets](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

If that still doesn't answer your question, you can also take per example a couple of different images per density folder (hdpi, ldpi, mdpi...) and just see which shows on your device or emulator.

Comment: ah. the magic behind it article is exactly what I was looking for. thanks very much.

Comment: Patience! (SO requires a question to hang out for a few minutes before it can be checkmarked... feel free to upvote my question if you feel it was worth answering! :)  ).